# Date component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, components

I want to know how I can add a date field like the type date

```
<input type="date" name="html5date">
```

I want an input component who include the slashes for date.

Thank's

Comment: What's the problem with above code?

Comment: Hello Gunter, when I use the type date I have some limitation, I can't remove the caleneder attached with type date and I can't edit the format of the date.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to use a custom date component or date picker component. Questions about external resources are discouraged on SO. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit or https://gitter.im/angular/angular to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the date picker component from ng2-bootstrap.
Check this: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap

Comment: any plnker for this ?

Comment: @hatim there is a live example on: [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker)